# I do not want to automatically change the database version

Tags: sql-server, version

version of my database is 661.
when i attach my database in new version of `sqlserver`, version of my database changed to 665 
Automatically.

I don't want to change version of my database.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent automatically database version upgrade when you're attaching/restoring database from lower to higher version of SQL Server.
Source: A lot of years of experience.

BUT, you can do a manual migration of higher version database into lower version by doing [THIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 database which are 661 version. Hopefully you  are trying to attach 2008 R2 to an SQL server 2008 instance but once the database has been upgraded to an 2008(665 version), it cannot be downgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2(661).

You need to uninstall SQL Express and reinstall the latest version to fix the problem.

Comment: You're sure there is no solution? (To avoid changing the version)

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop it changing the version, when an older version database is attached to a newer version of SQL server, it must perform these upgrade steps so before the database can be brought online on the new version.  These upgrades are internal to SQL server and include things like file format changes etc, they themselves should not affect behaviour of your user code (although the changes in the new version of the SQL engine might).

The only significant result of these upgrade steps is that the database can no longer be attached or restored to an older version of SQL server.